# Date time format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I need "24/01/2012" but Why it always returns "24/1/2012"

when I am using this

```
txtFilingStartDate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", (SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value.Day.ToString() + "/" + SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value.Month.ToString() + "/" + SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value.Year.ToString()));
```

Comment: if _SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value_ is a datetime value then pass it as a single parameter without all that string conversions for day, months and year

Answer (score 2):

Just do with this :

```
txtFilingStartDate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

`SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value` seems to be a DateTime value.
Then pass it directly without all that string conversions for day, months and year.

```
txtFilingStartDate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",  
                          (SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value);
```

The format string `"dd/MM/yyyy"` contains enough information to allow the Format method to prepare the resulting string directly from your DateTime value

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `String.Format` statement. You can do it with the Date's `ToString` method:

```
txtFilingStartDate = SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.ToString.Value("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

There's a lot more information on the [MSDN page for Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string and the format you specified for it is unrecognized.  Assuming that this is a datetime you are passing, don't do all that conversion first:

```
txtFilingStartDate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you format a string using a date/time formatting (`{0:dd/MM/yyyy}`) themethod is expecting an instance of `DateTime`, you are passing it a string

You probably want simply:

```
txtFilingStartDate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",SessionHelper.SearchFilingStartDate.Value);
```